# Preparing a ViewController before loading?

Tags: ios

I have a VC2 with a webView and a URL that takes a fair amount of time to load.  Is there a way to start loading VC2 while the user is still in VC1? So that when the user navigates from VC1 to VC2, the URL has already started loading ( or might even be finished and only requires rendering) ?

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the view controller from your storyboard instead of pushing the segue:

```
ResultsController *vc2 = [[ResultsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ResultsController" bundle:nil];
```

You should have a public method to start loading the site you want, or start loading it from viewcontroller's `-(id)init` method.

So after instantiating it you can call your load method

```
[vc2 startLoadingWeb];
```

And then to push it, just do:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.